# How we can make database resumable in perl script

Tags: db2, perl

I have a Perl code which connects with database and scan data from different different table. I face a problem if I lose my connection: it roll back all the transaction. How could I make the Perl script resume the connection and start the process from where the interruption took place? Can I use the Perl to resume the connection or any thing other technique to start the process from where the interruption took place if so could any one guide me with the steps please.

It is actually required because of we have lots of data and takes 1 week to scan all the data and insert in specific table, in between if we run database offline backup it disconnect all the connection and whatever transaction happens it roll back and need to run once again from the beginning.

We can commit the transaction whatever done but challenge is how we can start process from where the interruption took place so we don't require to run from the beginning.

Comment: You'll need to tell us more: which DBMS are you using? What is your table design? What process do you need to apply to the data?

Comment: I am using DB2.This is actually to find out SPI(Sensitive personal information) pattern from different different table and remove from their respective table. Basically I have 4 methods fetch,scan1,scan2,notify. fetch method is responsible for fetch details of the account to be scanned. Based on the fetch method scan1 method scan from XYZ table and so on.. Have we any technique is that whatever transaction happened before database connection failed be commit and when I will run perl program it start from where it aborted not from the beginning. Please help me out thanks in advance @Colin'tHart

Comment: Can any one tell me shall I use checkpoint restart in this scenario, if yes than please suggest me how I can implement..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can handle this problem:

1. Programmatically figure out how to store state, reconnect, and pick up where things left off.
2. Enable the database to use online backups, so the system can stay up 24/7. This would allow you to continue to process even when a backup is being taken (although I would question why something takes a full week to process....that just seems wrong to me....). To enable online backups, you need to enable archivable logging. This means switching the `LOGARCHMETH1` parameter. You will need to take at least one offline backup first after setting that parameter before you can take onlines.

Comment: Maybe adding the ability to store state, reconnect and pick up where things left off is a handy feature anyway. For testing, for system restarts.

Comment: Actually the problem in one of the method where we are inserting huge data. Suppose I have committed all the data till program got terminated. So can any one tell me is there any way to how I will identify at what place my program terminated and how it will start again inserting data from where it is left.

Comment: If you are using the IMPORT or LOAD process, there are ways to get it to continue. Please see the documentation for those two processes in the IBM Knowledge Center for your version of DB2.